# apache warnings

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

While I restart httpd service I see a thousand of warnings like the following:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/u79894/domains/edsdsdics.com.mx/private_html/lms] does not exist 
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/admin/domains/suspended/sketch] does not exist 
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/admin/domains/suspended/sketch] does not exist 
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/u79507/domains/centsdrointegdraldelaesaludd.com/private_html] does not exist 
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/u79875/domains/someberapyikal.com.mx/public_html] does not exist 
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/u80030/domains/elesdfo.com.mx/public_html/raptor] does not exist 
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/siecweb/domains/sidsdeb.net/public_html/clasesdenatacionsl] does not exist 
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/siecweb/domains/snirterwebi.net/public_html/cursosaquahod] does not exist 
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/arrietad/domains/arsdfr.com.mx/public_html] does not exist
```

How can I remove these warnings? Can I do this by a script?

Answer (score 1):

These warnings just mean that you've got some VirtualHosts set up with a DocumentRoot pointing to a non-existent directory; you should just remove the VirtualHosts from your Apache configuration.

How that's done depends on your configuration; I get the impression that you haven't set these up manually yourself, are you using some kind of control-panel to manage these sites?

Comment: yes, its a directadmin server